# Style MUI TextField Placeholder

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to make the placeholder font-weight to be 400 and the input font-weight to be 600 but it's not working.  I search for solutions here but none worked. The docs don't mention how to do it. Please, help!

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  input: {
    fontWeight: 600,
    "&::placeholder": {
      fontWeight: 400,
    },
  },
}));

function CustomizedInput() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      label="LOCATION"
      placeholder="Where are you going?"
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
      InputProps={{
        className: classes.input,
      }}
      variant="filled"
    />
  );
}

export { CustomizedInput };
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score -1):

Found out what I was doing wrong. It was a silly syntax error. I should use **classes** properties instead of ClassName.

```
InputProps={{
   classes: { input: classes.input }
}}
```

For more info about the difference between className and classes, please refer to [this post](http://this%20post)